# In Python how to pass a common object to different module files

Tags: python

I have various module files and want to share a common object (in this case a `logger`) to each of them. What is the best way to do this? I have a solution but it does not feel just right.

In pseudo code:

`module_1.py`

```
global logger

# module_1

def pass_logger_module1(plogger):
    global logger
    logger = plogger
```

`module_2.py`

```
global logger

# module_2

def pass_logger_module2(plogger):
    global logger
    logger = plogger
```

`main_module.py`

```
from module_1 import pass_logger_module1
from module_2 import pass_logger_module2

logger = set_logger(logfile, logformat, 'DEBUG')

pass_logger_module1(logger)
pass_logger_module2(logger)
```

Comment: That isn't how you should be using loggers. The logging module has the specific ability to define a parent logger with the settings you want and for child loggers to inherit them. You should read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks I will do. However in more general terms what is the best way to share a common object?

Comment: The best way is to pass it explicitly to each function that needs it and/or save it in objects that use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments this isn't the way use the `logging` module.

however a more general answer for "common object to different module files"
is to do it the other way around from your example, meaning:

`main_module.py`

```
# this is in global
logger = set_logger(logfile, logformat, 'DEBUG')
```

`module_1.py`

```
from main_module import logger
```

`module_2.py`

```
from main_module import logger
```

**EDIT**: 
to avoid making a circular import perhaps store the `logger` in a different module:

`settings.py`

```
# this is in global
logger = set_logger(logfile, logformat, 'DEBUG')
```

`main_module.py`

```
from settings import logger
```

Comment: this gives me circular import situation, but as suggested I can put the shared object in yet another module file and import from there...

Comment: Thanks that worked well. I had a setup module, however each module initiated its own instance of this setup, which worked ok for object that do not change in value, however I had my logger initiated several times. I have to rewrite it to make the setup object class objects and not instance objects...

Comment: It won't, You will get the same module that has already been imported (it will come from sys.modules). I encourage you check for yourself to see that it's true!

Answer (score 2):

First, define your custom logger in `custom_logger.py`

```
import logging
import sys


class CustomFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    err_fmt  = "[*] ERROR: %(msg)s"
    dbg_fmt  = "[-] DEBUG: %(module)s: %(lineno)d: %(msg)s"
    info_fmt = "[+] %(msg)s"

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(fmt="%(levelno)d: %(msg)s", datefmt=None, style='%')

    def format(self, record):
        # Save the original format configured by the user
        # when the logger formatter was instantiated
        format_orig = self._style._fmt

        # Replace the original format with one customized by logging level
        if record.levelno == logging.DEBUG:
            self._style._fmt = CustomFormatter.dbg_fmt

        elif record.levelno == logging.INFO:
            self._style._fmt = CustomFormatter.info_fmt

        elif record.levelno == logging.ERROR:
            self._style._fmt = CustomFormatter.err_fmt

        # Call the original formatter class to do the grunt work
        result = logging.Formatter.format(self, record)

        # Restore the original format configured by the user
        self._style._fmt = format_orig

        return result


class CustomLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        formatter = CustomFormatter()
        handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.addHandler(handler)
        self.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Then, in your other modules, import `CustomLogger`.

```
from custom_logger import CustomLogger


logger = CustomLogger(__name__)

logger.debug("Hello, world!")
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to expose your shared object through a third module, like so:

my_logger.py

```
logger = set_logger(logfile, logformat, 'DEBUG')
```

module_1.py

```
from my_logger import logger
...
```

module_2.py

```
from my_logger import logger
...
```

Your main module can then import both module_1 and module_2 without knowing about the logger and avoiding a circular import situation.